# Не могу подключить транзакции spring

Tags: java, spring, transaction

конфиг файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" 
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" >
    <property name="DataSource" ref="DataSource" />
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="add*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
    </tx:attributes>      
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor 
        id="advisor"
        pointcut-ref="pointcut"
        advice-ref="txAdvice" />
</aop:config>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut 
        id="pointcut" 
        expression="execution(* com.example.JdbcJobDAO.*(..))" />
</aop:config>

<bean id="DataSource" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
    <property name="username" value="system" />
    <property name="password" value="1234" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="DataSource" />
</bean>


<bean id="jdbcJobDAOImpl" class="com.example.JdbcJobDAOImpl">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />   
</bean>
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor': 
BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': 
BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'advisor': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'pointcut' while setting bean property 'pointcut'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'pointcut': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
```

я так понимаю, что я напутал в тэгах . Если их закоментить, то все нормально работает

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй заменить

```
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

на

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

т.к. у тебя нет объявления бина с id `txManager`

Comment: Неа.
Тут ошибка наверно в aop тэгах:
    <aop:config>
        <aop:advisor 
            id="advisor"
            pointcut-ref="pointcut"
            advice-ref="txAdvice" />
    </aop:config>
Если я их коменчу, все норм запускается

Comment: @Lestat выложи полный стек ошибки